# spring bean initializing instances differently via property wiring

Tags: spring

I have the following properties in a property file:

```
context1.property1=value1
context1.property2=value2
context1.property3=value3

context2.property1=value4
context2.property2=value5
context2.property3=value6
```

I have a bean with the following structure:

```
class Bean {
private property1;
private property2;
private property3;
}
```

Is there any way better to initialize 2 instances of Bean without writing something like:

```
<bean id="bean1" class="com.test.Bean">
 <property name="property1" value="${context1.value1}" />
 <property name="property2" value="${context1.value2}" />
 <property name="property3" value="${context1.value3}" />
</bean>

<bean id="bean2" class="com.test.Bean">
 <property name="property1" value="${context2.value1}" />
 <property name="property2" value="${context2.value2}" />
 <property name="property3" value="${context2.value3}" />
</bean>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [`PropertyOverrideConfigurer`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyOverrideConfigurer.html):

> Property resource configurer that overrides bean property values in an application context definition. It *pushes* values from a properties file into bean definitions.
>
> Configuration lines are expected to be of the following form:

```
beanName.property=value
```

> Example properties file:

```
dataSource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
dataSource.url=jdbc:mysql:mydb
```

## See also

- [Using PropertyOverrideConfigurer with Annotated Classes in Spring 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034732)

Comment: I'm not sure it helps much - I need to have a plain properties file(not Spring dependent) which I want to read also from maven. If I do this I'll need to have 2 property files.